# Let's assume that gradle code snippets are written in Groovy

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Code snippets in [gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle)-tagged questions are most likely to be written in [groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy), so I suggest to make groovy default code language for syntax highlighting in this case. Based on discussion related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260788/how-can-i-associate-specific-tag-with-specific-syntax-highlighting) question.

Comment: 9602 of 10255 are only tagged with the library, not the language...

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, this is exactly why I'm requesting this - practically all gradle code is groovy.

Answer (score 2):

Since gradle is the default build system for Android, you may see quite a few tagged (or mis-tagged) with gradle and Java code from their Android app.  And I'd expect them to use Java over groovy in the build system as well, because all the devs know Java and really nobody knows groovy.  Do you have any statistics to back up groovy being used more?  Because I don't think I've ever heard of groovy actually being used for anything anywhere.